# how to upload audio files to heroku server using python

Tags: python, web, heroku, audio

i have a python program that records sounds,and creates .wav files of these sounds.
now i have .wav files on my local machine. for example, recording1.wav.

now i want to upload these audio files to a herokuapp.com sever (using python code of course), for example:

upload recording1.wav from my local machine
to
Https://my-personal-Website.herokuapp.com/music
(my friend already created one for me.)

so that after, my friend could extract these files from his computer using java script.

how to do this?

i have spent days on this.
if i was unclear please say.

currenly this code does not compile because it says 'Payload Too Large':
[the function that uploads the audio file to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmbWc.png)

Comment: You want to know how to do it from the web side or the program side?

Comment: A program side, using a python script.
I would like to add python script to my exsiting program that once the recording is finshed the script will upload the .wav file to the server.

Comment: after i will upload the files to the server, my friend will extract them from the server to add to our website, but that's his job, my job is only the upload the .wav files from my local machine to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests

url = "put your URL here"
data = open(r'Path to .wav file', 'rb')}   
headers = {'content-type': 'audio/wav'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Chag kasher visamayach!

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: thank you very much sir, i will check with my partner if he got my post message.

Comment: No problem. Also, my name isn't sir.

Comment: Hey, i tried to use your code and it returned error 500 , i asked me friend and  now my friend tells me i need to send the file in "form- data" structure, when:
 key = "sound" 
and the 
value = the file itself.
can you help me with that?

Comment: very sorry to have to bother you

Comment: @רועיסלע Sorry shabbos just finished... let me get back to you soon

Comment: actully dude last night i think i got in

i just sent it like a multipart coded file like this:
`<html <code>

headers = {'content-type': 'audio/wav'}

    files = {'sound': (path, open(path, 'rb'), 'audio/wav', headers)  }
    r = requests.post(url, files= files)  # send the file to the server
<code>>`.

and that seem to work just fine.

Comment: @רועיסלע Nice!!